# Advanced Mysql query with case and when

Tags: mysql, case, notin, .when

I'm working in one scenario where I need to display few records from the table in which id does not exist in the list.

```
SELECT * FROM contract 
WHERE `id` NOT IN ( 
    CASE 
        WHEN type = 1 THEN '159,154' 
        WHEN type = 2 THEN '' 
        WHEN type = 3 THEN '' 
    END 
) 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Over here you can see that if contract type = 1 then the result should not display 159 & 154 records from the table. But 154 number record is also coming in the result which should not.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: `'159,154'` != `'159','154'`

Comment: thanks @lad2025, So how can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

```
...WHERE (type = 1 AND id NOT IN('159','154')) 
OR   (type = 2 AND id !='') 
OR   (type = 3 AND id !='')
```

Remove the quotes if the id is numeric so you can use a possible index.

Answer (score 0):

Use [MySQL INSTR() function](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-instr-function.php) as shown below:

```
SELECT * FROM contract 
WHERE INSTR(IF(type = 1, '159,154',''),`id`)<0
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Comment: I just converted the case to if, try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

```
SELECT * FROM contract 
WHERE (type = 1 AND id NOT IN ('159','154')) OR
    (type IN (2,3) AND id != '')
ORDER BY id DESC
```